# How can I count the number each variable type, appears in an Android class? e.g. int, string etc

Tags: java, android, regex, android-intent, android-activity

I've created a small Android application which reads in, a particular Android class (.java).

I'd like to (but currently don't know how):

- **Count the number each variable type is globally declared** *(as it is on the page, not during or after run-time etc.)* e.g.

*5 regular ints*, *3 regular strings*, *1 regular drawables*, *2 ArrayList of ints*

- **Count the number each variable type is locally declared, in each function** *(as it is on the page, not during or after run-time etc.)* e.g.

Function A: *2 regular ints*, *1 regular strings*

Function B: *3 regular drawables*, *4 ArrayList of ints*

- **Count the number of subroutines and functions, within the class** *(as it is on the page, not during or after run-time etc.)*

So far I've figured out the below, but due to the programmatic nature it doesn't work correctly:

```
        int numberofArrayLists = Collections.frequency(androidClass, "ArrayList<String>");
        int numberofIntLists = Collections.frequency(androidClass, "ArrayList<Int>");
        int numberofBooleanLists = Collections.frequency(androidClass, "ArrayList<Boolean>");
```

---

My code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        ArrayList<String> androidClass =  readAndroidClass("/sdcard/MainActivity.java");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public ArrayList<String> readAndroidClass(String classLocationString) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> androidClass = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileInputStream is;
    BufferedReader reader;
    final File classLocation = new File(classLocationString);

    if (classLocation.exists()) {
        is = new FileInputStream(classLocation);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while(line != null){
            androidClass.add(reader.readLine());
        }
    }

    return androidClass;
}
```

Example of an Android Java class to attempt the above:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        packageManager = getPackageManager();

        new LoadApplications().execute();
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                    applist.add(info);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return applist;
    }

    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                    R.layout.snippet_list_row, applist);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setListAdapter(listadaptor);
            progress.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null,
                    "Loading application info...");
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The question involves lot of code to write. So I am giving you an idea about how to move ahead. You can use this idea, customize it and modify it to make it better. Do let me know, if you need further help

**For counting variables at a class level:**

Create a skeleton for declaration statements:

> AccessMode OtherQualifier DataType VariableName EndMarker

```
where    
    AccessMode       =  { private, public, protected }    
    OtherQualifier   =  { static }    
    DataType         =  { int, char, string, boolean ..}    
    VariableName     =  { anything }    
    EndMarker        =  { ; , }
```

Write a function to detect whether a line is variable declaration or not

```
private boolean isLineVariableDeclaration(String line)
{
    this.hasAccessMode(line)
    // call other functions too ..
}

private bool hasAccessMode(String line)
{
    String access = line.Split(" ")[0].toLowerCase();

    // Check if AccessMode list has "access"
    // return true if it exists
}

private bool hasOtherQualifier(String line)
{
    String qualifier = line.Split(" ")[1].toLowerCase();

    // Check if OtherQualifier list has "qualifier"
    // return true if it exists
}

private bool hasDataType(String line)
{
    String dataType = line.Split(" ")[2].toLowerCase();

    // Check if DataType list has "dataType"
    // return true if it exists
}

private bool hasEndMarker(String line)
{
    String endMarker = line.Split(" ")[3].toLowerCase();

    // Statement looks like
    // private static int someVar;
    if(endMarker.Equals(";"))
    {
        // since this is line end
       // return true;
    }
    // Statement looks like
    // private static int someVar, someOtherVar;
    else if(endMarker.Equals(","))
    {
        // this means there are more variables so such type
        // do more to collect them
    }
}
```

---

**For counting variables inside a function:**

Create a skeleton for declaration statements:

> OtherQualifier DataType VariableName EndMarker

```
where      
    OtherQualifier   =  { static }    
    DataType         =  { int, char, string, boolean ..}    
    VariableName     =  { anything }    
    EndMarker        =  { ; , }
```

Using similar approach, write function here. 
For finding presence of "{" and "}" i.e. to detect function starting and closing do one thing:

- Set a `int bracesCounter = 0;`
- Whenever you encounter a `{` , increase `bracesCounter`
- Whenever you encounter a '}', decrease `bracesCounter`
- The moment your `bracesCounter` is zero again, you are out of function scope

---

**For counting number of if statements:**

Create a skeleton for statements:

> IF_KEYWORD LEFT_FUNCTION_BRACKET EXPRESSION RIGHT_FUNCTION_BRACKET
>   OTHER

```
where    
   IF_KEYWORD                    = { if }   
   LEFT_FUNCTION_BRACKET         = { ( }    
   EXPRESSION                    = { WITHOUT_OPERATOR, WITH_OPERATOR }       
   WITHOUT_OPERATOR              = { SIMPLE_OPERAND, OPERAND_WITH_FUNC }      
   SIMPLE_OPERAND                = { OPERAND }    
   OPERAND_WITH_FUNC             = { OPERAND.FUNC(), !OPERAND.FUNC() }     
   WITH_OPERATOR                 = { SIMPLE_OPERAND_WITH_OPERATOR,  OPERAND_WITH_FUNC_OPERATOR }   
   SIMPLE_OPERAND_WITH_OPERATOR  = { LEFT_OPERAND OPERATOR RIGHT_OPERAND }
   OPERAND_WITH_FUNC_OPERATOR    = { OPERAND_WITH_FUNC OPERATOR OPERAND_WITH_FUNC  }    
   LEFT_OPERAND                  = { OPERAND }   
   RIGHT_OPERAND                 = { OPERAND }    
   OPERATOR                      = { !=, ==, >, <, >=, <= }    
   OTHER                         = { RIGHT_CURLY_BRACES, NEW_LINE} 
   RIGHT_CURLY_BRACES            = { { } 
   NEW_LINE                      = { \n } 
so on and so forth..
```

However, above may seen tedious to you, if your requirement is just to count if's (or while's). So, instead, you can do this

- On any line if you encounter `if` check if it followed by `(`
- Set **brackets** = 1
- Now whenever you encounter `(` increase **brackets** by 1 and whenever you encounter whenever you encounter `)` decrease **brackets** by 1.
- When **brackets** become `0`, if condition statement is parsed successfully
- Please note: Keep on reading lines and lines, until **brackets** become zero
- Now, when brackets is `0` see if it is followed by `{`
- If yes, again set brackets = 1 Now whenever you encounter `{` increase **brackets** by 1 and whenever you encounter whenever you encounter `}` decrease
  **brackets** by 1.
- When **brackets** become `0`, if statement is parsed successfully

**You are done !**

**P.S.** Modify the algorithm above to suit your needs

Comment: The above is fantastic :-)
Could you please show me an example for how to test whether a variable is contained in the line. I'm asking as your "isLineVariableDeclaration", tests apples to functions but not to variables, as not all variables have "private, public, protected" before them

Comment: Also is there a way, that all possible data types could be programatically added to "DataType"? As this list could go on and on etc.

Comment: @RedSaint For finding whether is variable is contained in a line, use second definition which does not have AccessMode.

Comment: @RedSaint If you don't want to make extensive list of DataTypes, then you would have to assume that the program written is syntactically and semantically correct

Comment: @RedSaint, Say you have a variable declaration inside function `int myVar;` Skeleton for variable declaration inside functions is `OtherQualifier DataType VariableName EndMarker`. So feed this to `isLineVariableDeclaration(..)` Inside this function first check if OtherQualifier exists. So `line.Split(" ")[0]` does not match `static` which his OtherQualifier. So it doesn't have OtherQualifier. Since you don't have extensive list of DataTypes, so assume the next part (`int` in our case) is a DataType and next (`myVar` in our case) is a Varname.. so done..

Comment: You have been extremely helpful, do you by chance know, how I could count the number of if statements or while loops? I ask, as this could take place over several lines